# Converting a dictionary with values as list of dictionaries into pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Python dictionary which contains list as values corresponding to the keys. Now each list contains two another dictionaries and the data looks like this:

```
data = {'A': [{'Set1': {'Apple':1, 'Banana:2'}, 'Set2': {'Orange':1}],
        'B': [{'Set1': {'Apple':3, 'Banana:1', Carrot:2}, 'Set2': {}],
        'C': [{'Set1': {'Apple':1, 'Banana:2'}, 'Set2': {'Pineapple':5}]}
```

I want to convert this data to a `pandas DataFrame` and the result should be like this:

```
        Set1                                            Set2
A       {'Apple':1, 'Banana:2'}                         {'Orange':1} 
B       {'Set1': {'Apple':3, 'Banana:1', Carrot:2}      {}
C       {'Apple':1, 'Banana:2'}                         {'Pineapple':5}
```

How can I achieve this?

P.S:  I tried `pd.DataFrame(data)` and `pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)` but that didn't work.

Comment: some of the `'` are wrong in the sample data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need:

```
data = {'A': [{'Set1': {'Apple':1, 'Banana':2}, 'Set2': {'Orange':1}}],
        'B': [{'Set1': {'Apple':3, 'Banana':1, 'Carrot':2}, 'Set2': {}}],
        'C': [{'Set1': {'Apple':1, 'Banana':2}, 'Set2': {'Pineapple':5}}]}

df = (pd.concat({k: pd.DataFrame(v) for k, v in data.items()})
        .reset_index(level=1, drop=True))
print (df)
                                     Set1              Set2
A               {'Banana': 2, 'Apple': 1}     {'Orange': 1}
B  {'Carrot': 2, 'Banana': 1, 'Apple': 3}                {}
C               {'Banana': 2, 'Apple': 1}  {'Pineapple': 5}
```

Comment: Awesome!! Thanks @jerzael

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution via a dictionary comprehension:

```
data = {'A': [{'Set1': {'Apple':1, 'Banana':2}, 'Set2': {'Orange':1}}],
        'B': [{'Set1': {'Apple':3, 'Banana':1, 'Carrot':2}, 'Set2': {}}],
        'C': [{'Set1': {'Apple':1, 'Banana':2}, 'Set2': {'Pineapple':5}}]}

df = pd.DataFrame({i: [data[k][0][i] for k in data] for i in data['A'][0]},
                  index=data)

#                                      Set1              Set2
# A               {'Apple': 1, 'Banana': 2}     {'Orange': 1}
# B  {'Apple': 3, 'Banana': 1, 'Carrot': 2}                {}
# C               {'Apple': 1, 'Banana': 2}  {'Pineapple': 5}
```